# dropdownlist how to hide one table from the other depending on the choice?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist with two fields and two listview, depending on the option I choose from the dropdown one of the two listview must hide

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  BackColor="#3B5998"  DataTextField="DenominazioneTipo" DataValueField="IdTipo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Tipocliente]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: do you want to show list view based on drop down selection by jquery or c#. If you want to use c# just use OnSelectedIndex Changed

Comment: Can you show the code behind that you're using to try and determine which list view to show?

Comment: in the dropdown list I have two options depending on the option I must show one of the two listview I have

Comment: in codebehind I have nothing because I don't know what event to use

Comment: Use protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { } then use the DropDownList1.SelectedValue. Presumably you will want an if statement or switch using that value to display the appropriate list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and based on index or selected value you can show and hide

in .aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  BackColor="#3B5998"  DataTextField="DenominazioneTipo" DataValueField="IdTipo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

in .aspx.cs

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
   {
       ListView1.Visible = true;
       ListView2.Visible = false;
   }
   else if(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
   {
       ListView1.Visible = false;
       ListView2.Visible = true;
   }
}
```